# What are the female parts called?

Tags: terminology

What is the proper term for the "female" section of the piece that the "studs" insert into? I have heard "pipes", "tubes", "underbits". Is there an actual term for the female section?

Comment: Interesting question. To help finding a good term, it would be useful with a good example to use this in a phrase. Do you have an example of use in a natural context?

Comment: It was an analogy to demonstrate how you can plug an API into your website. So, the statement went something like "You have a LEGO piece (representing the API) with it's studs and you need to attach it to your website, so you need do build the [underbits/tubes/stud receptacle] to plug the API into."

Comment: See also this question for naming other features of a brick: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/is-there-an-official-lego-terminology-for-the-features-of-basic-pieces

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chapter 1, Page 4, The Unofficial LEGO Builder's Guide:

> The *tube* is the other half of the mechanism that helps bricks stick
>   together. Tubes capture the studs so that you can join LEGO elements
>   and know they won't fall apart.

Comment: I have to disagree on that somewhat, or at least try to add some undertone. The tubes do indeed capture the studs, but not by themselves: the studs are (usually) captured between tubes, or between tubes and brick walls; they don't "insert into" them in conventional builds. Also, not all parts feature tubes, so what would you call the underside of a 1x1 brick?

Comment: The underside of a 1x1 brick? How about "The square version of the tube that is the bottom of a 1x1 round brick"?

Answer (score 8):

[Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=stud%20receptacle) (at the time of writing) has 5 catalog items using the term 'stud receptacle'.

Answer (score 4):

Members of the French club [FreeLUG](http://www.freelug.fr/) refers to these as *[antistuds](http://www.google.be/search?q=antistud)*, and there is [at least one](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/32530) LDraw part that uses that same naming. Considering a lot of other parts don't, however, it's probably not widely accepted. And it's [not valid at Scrabble](http://www.anagrammer.com/scrabble/antistud) either.

You could also use *mortise* by analogy with the [woodworking assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortise_and_tenon) (a stud is also usually called *tenon* in French), but again, I've never heard it in LEGO circles. *Slot* might be appropriate too.

Comment: I think "slot" would be more descriptive of an open spot in a construction where a particular part fits.